# How to load visual placeholder content before actual content itself?

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

How can i make load such kind of placeholder before load actual content?
I want to show meaningful paint to end user rather than white empty screen,but i don't have enough information how to do it.

Comment: Please post your attempt at this problem.

Comment: use the alt tag in image. I think this a duplicate just research more

Comment: i don't know how to make placeholder content visible before real content itself.
And make disappear placeholder content after main content loaded.

Comment: A quick google search finds you many articles ( [example](https://css-tricks.com/building-skeleton-screens-css-custom-properties/) ). Questions like these tend to be off-topic because they're too broad, often asking for an external source, and opinion-based (everybody has their own implementation).

Comment: Read my question carefully! i was asking for practical help,i know there're a lot of source which provide with only placeholder.Having it doesn't solve problem.
Don't answer for the sake of answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React, check this out:

https://github.com/buildo/react-placeholder

If not, here's a jQuery implementation:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Content-Placeholder-Plugin-jQuery-Skeleton-Loader.html

Good luck!

Comment: You're probably getting downvoted because you're providing a link to an external resources. Questions like that are off-topic because they're opinion-based, and easily Googleable, and therefore the answers will often be off-topic too.

Answer (score 0):

By that rationale the downvote itself would be off-topic. I remember when SO was a helpful resource, upsetting to see it decline so rapidly.